# How would you go about separating strings in a file if they may contain any arbitary characters?

Tags: java, string

I'm currently writing a Java program which involves goals. It's basically a to-do list. Each goal has a few strings, such as name, description etc. I can save and load these goals to a file. My issue was separating the strings - I couldn't think of a character that couldn't be in the string itself. I ended up prefixing each string with it's length and then a colon.

I'm sure there is something in the Java API that will handle this, like ObjectOutputStream. I'm curious about the 'general case', though. This must be an issue for any program that saves and loads strings from a file without being able to assume anything about the string. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: There are many options and formats. Think about JSON or CSV, most formats tend to denote a string by surrounding text with double quotes.

Comment: Falls under "too broad", I'd say, but you can probably summarize the approaches as "[uses escape characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)" (including JSON, CSV, ...) and "type-length-value encoding" (e.g. ASN.1 DER and the [Java Serialization Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html#5849)).

Comment: My issue is that the string itself may contain commas or double quotes. I thought about using a null character as a separator but it turns out pretty much anything can be typed into a text field.

Comment: You can always parse the contents of the text field and replace double quotes with escaped double quotes (`\"`), or remove unwanted characters like the nul character.

Comment: Those are great ideas and I'm embarrassed I didn't just do that.

Comment: It depends on how you added the Strings to the file. Please paste the code that writes the Strings to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of ways to handle your case, e.g:

1. Encoding your String with something like base64
2. Applying a well defined format, e.g. JSON or CSV

There are tons of tools support you including:

- [Apache Commons codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) for base64 encoding/decoding
- [Jaskson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) for JSON serializing/deserializing
- [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) for csv serializing/deserializing